# Understanding fork command in operating system

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am just playing with fork command I have written a following command in my ubuntu virtual machine

```
int main()
{
 printf("what the heck dude?");
 int pid=fork();
 printf("Beginning of Child or Parent")
 if(pid==0)
   {  
     //wait()                                 //1
     printf("I am Child with pid %d",pid);
     //wait()                                 //2
   }
 else
  {
    //wait()                                 //3
    printf("I am Parent with pid %d",pid);
    //wait()                                 //4
  }
printf("End of Child or Parent")
}
```

I have put wait in different parts of if and else one by one. these numerals show positions of wait.

by putting wait at `//4` position only I got following weird output

```
What the heck dude?

Beginning of Child or Parent

Beginning of Child or Parent

I am a Child Process with pid 0

End of Child or Parent

End of Child or Parent
```

I am not getting what is happening here.Putting wait at other positions output was ok.
If anybody could explain me what is happening here?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Your output does not match your code. And please state explicitly what you expect the output to be and why you find the actual output "weird".

Comment: Please show your actual code, not code you typed up by hand for this question. Your code and your printouts don't match, and your code also has several syntax errors. Plus, we need to see your actual `wait` function calls because `wait();` with no parameters isn't going to compile.

Comment: Meanwhile, some things to consider: (a) if your printouts don't end with `\n` that can mess up output; (b) using `printf` after forking isn't a great idea because C's stdio library might buffer output, causing the parent and child to have duplicated buffers. It's better to either use lower-level `write()` calls or call `exec()` from one of the forked processes to avoid this problem.

Comment: ^ `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()` should alleviate that problem. (Or does that not apply when using `fork` too?)

Comment: Calling `wait()` in the child will have no effect. `wait()` only does something if the process has children.

Comment: Sorry for that stupid syntax guys.I was wondering why the statement in the parent block is not getting executed in this case in all other cases it is being executed?

Comment: Since you're here and responding to comments, please address Alan's and my initial comments. Please show your real code with a proper [mcve]. Click that link for further details. Your example is *minimal* (thank you, that's rare and much appreciated) but is not *complete* and *verifiable*.